# Loop thru [] of JSX.Elements and dynamically add classes to it

Tags: reactjs

it seems this is quite an edge case problem, but imagine if I already had an [] of JSX.Elements (divs in particular) that already has classes on them.

I'd like to dynamically add a className to it, is this possible? I've tried to forEach it and add el.props.className="", but it's a readOnly prop.

```
let allDivs = graphHeights.map((height) => {
    return (
        <div style={{ height: height }} className={styles["mini-div"]}></div>
    );
});
```

Now I wish to loop through the above [] of allDivs, and add specific classNames to them

Comment: Can you share your current code?

Comment: Can you not apply the correct className in the `.map`? What are the rules that govern which element gets which class?

Answer (score 0):

When you run your code,

```js
<div style={{ height: height }} className={styles["mini-div"]}></div>
```

will return a react element, not a component. Sort of like instances of react components.

So what you have is an array of react elements.

To add props to react element, you need to use cloneElement

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement

```js
let allDivsChanged = allDivs.map(element => {
  return React.cloneElement(element, { className: "replaceClassName" });
});
```